# how to distribute different values of one column in the new column fields

Tags: ms-access

In my table for duplicate "line no" I have different "contractor" like below.

```
LINE NO     CONTRACTOR

L-0001      C-1000
L-0001      C-2000
L-0003      C-6000
L-0003      C-8000
L-0003      C-9000
L-0004      C-5000
```

Now I would like to make a query for transposing values like below:

```
LINE NO     CONTRACTOR1     CONTRACTOR2         CONTRACTOR3

L-0001      C-1000          C-2000
L-0003      C-6000          C-8000              C-9000
L-0004      C-5000
```

Please help how I have to make this query?

---

i made a query that ranking data of my table like below:

```
  SELECT A.[line no], A.contractor, Count(*) AS ranking, "contractor" & [ranking] AS   contractor_rank
     FROM Table2 AS A INNER JOIN Table2 AS B ON (A.contractor>=B.contractor) AND (A.[line no] = B.[line no])
    GROUP BY A.[line no], A.contractor;
```

then made a cross tab query for top query like below:

```
    TRANSFORM First(Query4.contractor) AS FirstOfcontractor
    SELECT Query4.[line no]
  FROM Query4
  GROUP BY Query4.[line no]
  PIVOT Query4.contractor_rank;
```

now it works.

i add

Comment: You need to edit your question to tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried to do it by cross tab query or pivot table, but it did not work. i need query make new column field. for example for specific (line no ) if i have 3 contractors, it makes new fields (contractor1,contractor2,contractor3) and then put values in these fields.

Comment: Hi Gord Thompson, i tried to do like the queries added in my question and it seems works, and you are right after 89 question i have to try more.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working. Please consider posting your working code as an answer and then accepting it. (It's perfectly okay to answer your own question on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a query that ranking data of my table like below:

```
  SELECT A.[line no], A.contractor, Count(*) AS ranking, "contractor" & [ranking] AS     contractor_rank
 FROM Table2 AS A INNER JOIN Table2 AS B ON (A.contractor>=B.contractor) AND (A.[line no] = B.[line no])
GROUP BY A.[line no], A.contractor;
```

then made a cross tab query for top query like below:

```
TRANSFORM First(Query4.contractor) AS FirstOfcontractor
SELECT Query4.[line no]
FROM Query4
GROUP BY Query4.[line no]
 PIVOT Query4.contractor_rank;
```

now it works.